# Unusual repos error when install postgresql11 on CentOS7

Tags: centos, postgresql

I was try to install postgresql11 on CentOS7. I found the instruction of install in offical site:
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

Then I follow it's step and select following parameter:

```
1.version: 11
2.platform: RedHat Enterprise,CentOS, Scientific or Oracle version 7
3.architecture: x86_64
```

Got the command for install the resository RPM:

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

I run it on server successful. Then I try to run the command for install the client packages:

```
yum install postgresql11
```

I got following error when I execute this command:

```
File contains parsing errors: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo
    [line 196]: [pgdg96-updates-debuginfo]k
    [line 203]: [pgdg95-updates-debuginfo]k
```

I met same error when I try to erase this package use command:

```
yum erase pgdg-redhat-repo
```

I couldn't found any content in /etc/yum.repos.d use command:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/ && grep pgdg-redhat-all.repo ./*
```

I had already search this error in google and seems no one met this error. Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They seem to have made a packaging error when preparing that rpm. In `/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo`, you'll find a section

```
[pgdg10-updates-debuginfo]
name=PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Debuginfo
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/debug/10/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG

[pgdg96-updates-debuginfo]k
name=PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Debuginfo
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/debug/9.6/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG

[pgdg95-updates-debuginfo]k
name=PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS $releasever - $basearch - Debuginfo
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/debug/9.5/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG

# Debuginfo/debugsource packages for testing repos
# Available for 9.6 and above.
```

Just remove the `k`s after the `]` and you should be fine. [This bug has already been reported](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16295-7ca0beea2d6f6ad8%40postgresql.org)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your help and report bug to fix the problem